# Creating a new lead with Zapier, not setting Record Type correctly

Tags: leads, record-type

I'm using Zapier to create a new lead in Salesforce with data from a Fluidsurveys form. It all works fine except the Record Type is not being set correctly and I can't figure out why.

Checking the task history in Zapier, the RecordTypeId field is set as follows when it creates a new lead:

RecordTypeId:   01290000000TIw3AAG

This is the correct RecordTypeId (I checked by putting the id into a URL in Salesforce i.e. https://ap1.salesforce.com/setup/ui/recordtypefields.jsp?id=01290000000TIw3AAG and it links to the correct Record Type).

But when I check the new lead in Salesforce, all the other fields are correct but the Record Type is set to the default record type rather than the one which is given by the above id.

The profile I'm using i.e. the one Zapier logs in with, has all record types available to it.

Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Explanation of Zapier: "Zapier connects the web apps you use to easily move your data and automate tedious tasks." I use it to grab data from a new Fluidsurvey completed response and create new leads in Salesforce.

Some additional info after experimentation:

- When I changed the default record type on the profile I'm using (System Administrator), it made no difference i.e. the lead still came through as the wrong record type
- Then I remembered there was an assignment rule which changes the owner of the lead when created. So when I changed the default record type for the profile of new user to a different default, it did change the record type to that.

Comment: Check if the profile that you're using to create the lead has the record type enabled for it

Comment: The profile I'm using has all record types available to it. The default record type is the one that is being assigned when I create leads via Zapier, as described above.

Comment: Is the record type active? :)

Comment: Yeah it is active

Comment: That's weird, usually those things cause this problem. I am not familiar with Zapier, do you mind explaining the concept of how the integration to Salesforce works in short points?

Comment: Edited the question to include Zapier explanation

Comment: Is there either a trigger or workflow rule / field update in Salesforce that is changing the Record Type by chance?

Comment: So basically this is a web-to-lead form?

Comment: @JamesLoghry I don't have any workflow rules or field updates set up.

Comment: @e-bacho2.0 it's very similar I imagine, though I've not used web-to-lead before

Comment: Have you checked for triggers on the Lead object as @JamesLoghry mentioned?

Comment: There's no triggers set up

Comment: Added a bit more info to the question

Answer (score 1):

We ran into a similar issue on my Zapier integration from 123ContactForms to Salesforce. Turns out **we did not have a Lead Assignment Rule** to catch those records and assign to a user/queue. As a result, they would be assigned to the Default User, and would assume a Default RecordType. So, by catching them incoming with the recordtype and then reassigning to a specific user/queue, they kept the initial recordtype. I also believe you could have fixed this by changing "Use Assignment Rules" = No (rather than Yes) in the Zapier template.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't use Zapier never, but if you can change the html code (I suppose that you can), you can just add this line to the html code

```
<input  type="hidden" id="lead_source" name="lead_source" value="Web">
```

It will pass the value "web" to the field "Lead Source", and the type "hidden" will make it invisible, so this will be transparent to the new lead.